# can i send key:value in function as parameter in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to send object in my jquery function and then use its value in my function.

```
function sample(i,e){
  for(prop in i) {
    console.log(i[prop]);
  }
}
```

I want to call this function like this way:

```
sample({i:foo,e:bar});
```

I only get first object value on console, so how i get second object value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works. Everything is fine. Whats the problem?

Comment: okay thanks guys to clear my doubt. :)

Comment: Try `sample({i:'foo',e:'bar'});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
sample({i:foo,e:bar});
```

...`sample` receives **one** argument: An object with the properties `i` and `e` (whose values are taken from the values of the variables `foo` and `bar` as of when `{i:foo,e:bar}` is evaluated prior to being passed to the function). So you can either loop over that argument (as you do in your example, just ditch the `e` argument that you aren't using), or use the properties directly. You do need to declare your `prop` variable, though; right now, your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*.

Example:

```js
function sample(obj){
  var key;
  for (key in obj) {
    console.log(key + ": " + obj[key]);
  }
  
  console.log("Direct access - i: " + obj.i);
  console.log("Direct access - e: " + obj.e);
}

var foo = "this is foo";
var bar = "this is bar";
sample({i:foo,e:bar});
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation and now i'm clear about this.

Answer (score 0):

`{i:foo,e:bar}` will be supplied to first argument in `i` variable of  `sample` function, You can access it like `i.i` and `i.e`

```js
function sample(i){
  for(prop in i) {
    console.log(i[prop]);
  }
}

sample({i:"foo",e:"bar"});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
sample( {i:foo, e:bar} );
```

you're creating a new object with properties `i` and `e`

The function definition for this would be:

```
function sample(o) {
    console.log(o.i);  // == foo
    console.log(o.e);  // == bar
}
```

Due to how `for` loops works, this does work, but might not be what you're expecting:

```
for(prop in o) {
    console.log(o[prop]);
}
// two outputs, foo and bar
```